# can't get the search list of snippet on addMarker in Android Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am having problem on how to use `onQueryTextSubmit` and `onQueryTextChange` what I want is to have a searchable Plate No. using the snippet on my addMarker. My problem right now is I am a case sensitive incorrect value under my onQueryTextSubmit. I added my marker on a list however, `I am getting always the last value not all values.` Pls. help

Marker

```
      public void vehicleRequest_validate() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();

        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();

        networkAPI = retrofit.create(NetworkAPI.class);

        VehicleRequestPojo loginRequest = new VehicleRequestPojo(MainActivity.ucsi_num, client_table, markutype);

        Call<JsonElement> call = networkAPI.loginRequest(loginRequest);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
                // success response
                if (response.body().isJsonArray()) {
                    JsonArray objectWhichYouNeed = response.body().getAsJsonArray();
                    System.out.println(objectWhichYouNeed + " Object");

                    for (int i = 0; i < response.body().getAsJsonArray().size(); i++) {
                        JsonElement plate_num_array = response.body().getAsJsonArray().get(i);
                        JsonObject plate_num_obj = plate_num_array.getAsJsonObject();
                        String plate_n = plate_num_obj.get("plate_num").toString();
                        String plate_nString = plate_n;
                        plate_nString = plate_nString.replace("\"", "");
                        String plate_num = String.valueOf(plate_nString);

                        JsonElement gps_num_array = response.body().getAsJsonArray().get(i);
                        JsonObject gps_num_obj = gps_num_array.getAsJsonObject();
                        String gps_num = gps_num_obj.get("gps_num").toString();

                        JsonElement location_array = response.body().getAsJsonArray().get(i);
                        JsonObject location_obj = location_array.getAsJsonObject();
                        String location = location_obj.get("location").toString();

                        JsonElement date_array = response.body().getAsJsonArray().get(i);
                        JsonObject date_obj = date_array.getAsJsonObject();
                        String date = date_obj.get("date").toString();

                        JsonElement time_array = response.body().getAsJsonArray().get(i);
                        JsonObject time_obj = time_array.getAsJsonObject();
                        String time = time_obj.get("time").toString();

                        JsonElement lat_array = response.body().getAsJsonArray().get(i);
                        JsonObject lat_obj = lat_array.getAsJsonObject();
                        String lati = lat_obj.get("lat").toString();
                        String latiString = lati;
                        latiString = latiString.replace("\"", "");
                        String lat = String.valueOf(latiString);

                        JsonElement lng_array = response.body().getAsJsonArray().get(i);
                        JsonObject lng_obj = lng_array.getAsJsonObject();
                        String longi = lng_obj.get("lng").toString();
                        String longiString = longi;
                        longiString = longiString.replace("\"", "");
                        String lng = String.valueOf(longiString);

                        JsonElement engine_array = response.body().getAsJsonArray().get(i);
                        JsonObject engine_obj = engine_array.getAsJsonObject();
                        String engine = engine_obj.get("engine").toString();

                        JsonElement remarks_array = response.body().getAsJsonArray().get(i);
                        JsonObject remarks_obj = remarks_array.getAsJsonObject();
                        String remarks = remarks_obj.get("remarks").toString();

                        if (lat != null && !lat.equals("null")
                                && (lng != null && !lng.equals("null")
                                || (lat != "" && lat != "")
                                && lng != "") && (lng != "")) {

                            Double d = Double.parseDouble(lat);
                            Double d2 = Double.parseDouble(lng);
                            createMarker(d, d2, plate_num);
                        }

                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Not a JSONArray.");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
                // failure response
                System.out.println(call.toString());
            }

        });
    }

    public void createMarker(Double latitude, final Double longitude, String Plate_num) {
        BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus);

        list = new ArrayList<Marker>();

        Marker marker = mMapFragment.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .title("Plate No.")
                .snippet(Plate_num)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
        list.add(marker);

/*        mMapFragment.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                .title("Plate No.")
                .snippet(Plate_num)
                .icon(image));*/

        mMapFragment.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                marker.hideInfoWindow();
            }
        });

        mMapFragment.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 9.0f));

        mMapFragment.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
                vm = new VehicleMap();

                vm.setSnippet(marker.getSnippet());
                vm.setPlate_num(marker.getSnippet());

                latitudeG = marker.getPosition().latitude;
                longitudeG = marker.getPosition().longitude;

                marker.showInfoWindow();

                BottomSheetDialogFragment bottomSheetDialogFragment = new BottomSheetModalFragment(activity);
                bottomSheetDialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), bottomSheetDialogFragment.getTag());

                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMapFragment = googleMap;
 /*       LatLng latlong = new LatLng(12.405888, 123.273419);
        CameraUpdate cameraPosition = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlong, 16);
        mMap.moveCamera(cameraPosition);
        mMap.animateCamera(cameraPosition);*/

        new GetVehicles().execute();
        mMapFragment.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(12.405888, 123.273419), 6));
//        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(12.405888, 123.273419), 13));

        setUpMap();
    }
```

Here I want to pass the value of search title="Plate No." latitude and longitude to the LatLng value.

```
 public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    centerMarker(query);
    for(Marker m : list) {
        System.out.println(m.getSnippet() + m.getTitle() + m.getPosition() + " snippet");
        if(m.getSnippet().equals(query)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You searched for: " + query , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mMapFragment.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(m.getPosition(), 9.0f));
            break; // stop the loop
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am getting always the last value not all values.

You only get **one value** (...probably) because you are making a brand new list every method call to `createMarker(d, d2, plate_num)`

```
public void createMarker(Double latitude, final Double longitude, String Plate_num) {
        BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bus);

        // list = new ArrayList<Marker>(); // Stop doing this!
```